# Can i make a function to create table and name it with a parameter used when called?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a function that, when I call it, I can pass it a name and it will make a table for me. I then want it to return the table so I can use it. My code does make a table but I can't seem to access it. I'm thinking Lua is having trouble naming after an argument, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is a sample code of what I am trying to accomplish:

**Tablemaker.lua:**

```
Tabler = {}
Tabler.init = function (n,x,y,z)
--This is where i think it is messing up
    N = {}
    N.a = x
    N.b = y
    N.c = z
    --had a print function here so i know the table is made.
    I am leaving it out for you guys.
    --not sure if i need it but i put return here.
    Return n
End
```

**Main.lua:**

```
Require ("Tablemaker.lua")

Tabler.init (meow,15,32,45)
--a sepaeate print function here to verify i can access my
table. When the console tries to print, it gives meow = nil.
Which i am assuming the table is not properly named meow and
is instead named n. However using print(n.a) for example gives
n = nil also.
Print(meow.a .. " " .. meow.b .. " " .. meow.c)
```

And thats about it. I'm trying to make a vector class (not sure why one isn't in Lua), but even without vectors I want to be able to pass names into functions. What should i do?

Comment: You make table `N`, but return absolutely different value `n`.

Comment: That was an error in posting my sample code -- the code i has used the same value for both. But your other suggestion works, thanks!

Comment: `Tabler.init = function(n,x,y,z) _G[n] = {a=x, b=y, c=z} end`, usage: `Tabler.init("meow",15,32,45)`

Comment: It might help to understand that, a table, like any other type of Lua value, does not have a name. A variable has a name and it references a value. So, the function you've described must do two things: 1) create a table value 2) create a variable that references it. Or, use a function like @Oleg shows, and let the caller deal with issues concerning variables. The only things good about variables are 1) they name concepts and 2) their scopes control the lifetime of the objects they reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make function create named table in global, but why would you ever need that? Just return it and assign it to whatever you like be it global or local or whatever. Globals are bad anyway.

```
Tabler = {}
Tabler.init = function (x,y,z)
    N = {}
    N.a = x
    N.b = y
    N.c = z
    Return N
End
```

---

```
Require ("Tablemaker.lua")

local meow = Tabler.init(15,32,45)
Print(meow.a .. " " .. meow.b .. " " .. meow.c)
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I had no idea you could reassign the table name like that(or does it not have a default name in the function?)

Comment: @EmperorAnsem: What are you talking about? Have you never used return values from functions before? Tables don't have names anymore than the number 3 has a name.

Comment: @EmperorAnsem, you assign an empty table to another variable `Tabler` in the very first line. Table is just a value.